# SQL Запрос: Вывести user_id пользователей, у которых единственный активный день выпал на 5 августа

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:
[image: timestamp - дата посещения страницы]

Нужно найти пользователей (user_id), у которых единственный активный день (хотя бы 1 посещение любого url) выпал на 2022-08-05.

Answer (score 2):

Тут в любом случае скан таблицы, так что самое простое

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MIN(DATE(timestamp)) = '2022-08-05' AND MAX(DATE(timestamp)) = '2022-08-05'
```

Если без приведения типов, то можно так(теоритически при индексе на user_id, timestamp будет быстрее):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MIN(timestamp) >= '2022-08-05' AND MAX(timestamp) < '2022-08-06'
```

Можно более классически с DISTINCT, но тут уже сортировка внутри окна по user_id - так себе по производительности:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(timestamp)) = 1 AND MAX(DATE(timestamp)) = '2022-08-05'
```

Можно ещё множествами:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2022-08-05'
EXCEPT
SELECT user_id
FROM table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) <> '2022-08-05'
```

или EXISTS

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM table t1
WHERE DATE(t1.timestamp) = '2022-08-05'
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT t2.user_id
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND DATE(t2.timestamp) <> '2022-08-05'
  )
```

Попробуйте все, что подойдёт лучше.

ps: последние 2 не советую:) Так привёл, для общего развития...

Comment: 2й вариант наименее затратный и ориентирован на индекс(не важно, есть он сейчас или нет). Я бы на нём остановился.

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin согласен, но я молодой был

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where concat(col1,col2,col3,col4) like '%2022-08-05%'
```

Для определения колонок

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас в базе идёт сохранение всех входов то можно попробовать таким вот образом. (Если дополнительных условий нет):

```
SELECT user_id FROM ваша_таблица WHERE timestamp LIKE '2022-08-05%';
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тут загвоздка именно в том, что надо найти пользователя(ей), которые заходили на страницы только 5 августа и никогда больше.
Сохранение всех входов пользователей в БД есть)

Comment: Так запрос который я вам скинул и так выводит только тех пользователей которые заходили 5 августа 2022г

Comment: Или вам нужно чтобы 5 августа любого года?